# how to use user-defined jstl core tags inside ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, jstl

I have created a custom tag using the jstl core. Here is the code I placed in c.tld.

This code just gets the value in xml file based on the code passed.

```
    <tag>
        <name>code</name>
        <tag-class>com.acss.util.CodeTagSample</tag-class>
        <body-content>JSP</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>type</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>code</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
      </tag>
```

Here is my ajax code.

This code will show popup screen, and reload the values in jQuery DataTable

```
$('#attendanceModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var empId = button.data('whatever'); 
    var url = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/attendance/' + empId;
    $("#attendance-table-body").empty();

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET',
        url         : url,
        success     : function(resp) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( resp );

            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                tr = '<tr>';
                tr+="<td>"+obj[i].Date+"</td>";
                tr+="<td>" + obj[i].Time+ "</td>";
                tr+="<td>"+readEventCode(obj[i].nTNAEvent)+"</td>";
                tr+='</tr>';
               $("#attendance-table-body").append(tr);
            }
        },
        error       : function() {
            //
        }
    });

});

function readEventCode(eventCode) {
    return <c:code type="EVENTCODE" code=""+eventCode+"" />;
}
```

Then when I try to reload the page (not yet calling the ajax function), the return string in readEventCode() function becomes **blank** as I checked the source code by browser.

Comment: @BalusC it is not duplicate. I've checked that thread, and it's very different to my question

Comment: Just substitute "Servlet" in duplicate by "any Java code", then exactly the same answer applies.